# C Low Level File I/O O_APPEND flag not working

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void cp(char* src, char* dest)
{
  int       infile, outfile;
  const int BUFF_SIZE = 65536;
  struct    stat instats, outstats;
  long      bytes;
  char      *buff;

  /* Open source and destination files */
  if ((infile = open(src, O_RDONLY)) == -1) exit(1);
  if ((outfile = open(dest, O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT)) == -1) exit(1);

  /* Calculate optimal buffer size */
  //fstat(infile, &instats);
  //fstat(outfile, &outstats);

  //optimal = LCM(instats.st_blksize, outfile.st_blksize);
  //buff_size = MIN(optimal, 65536);
  buff = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFF_SIZE);

  /* Copy file */
  while((bytes = read(infile, buff, BUFF_SIZE)) > 0)
    write(outfile, buff, bytes);
  close(infile);
  close(outfile);
  free(buff);
}

int main()
{
  DIR* dirp;
  dirp = opendir(".");
  if(dirp == NULL) exit(1);
  else
  {
    struct dirent* dentry;
    dentry = readdir(dirp);

    while(dentry != NULL)
    {
      struct stat fst;
      int statr = stat(dentry->d_name, &fst);
      char* src = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (2 + 1024));
      src = strcpy(src, "./");
      src = strcat(src, dentry->d_name);
      //printf("%s", src);
      if(!statr)
      {
        if(S_ISREG(fst.st_mode))
        {
          printf("NAME: %s\n", src);
          cp(src, "archive");
        }
      }
      dentry = readdir(dirp);
      free(src);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This is my current code. I want to take all regular files in the working directory and append their contents to a file called "archive" so that they may be recreated from the archive file. I don't quite know what is going wrong as I am opening the archive file with O_APPEND flag and the data I'm attempting to write is not appending to the file.

Comment: You don't need to append the filename to `./`. Just using the filename by itself will look in the current directory.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html "The mode argument **must be supplied** if O_CREAT or O_TMPFILE is specified in flags"

Comment: You should print an error message when `open()` returns `-1` so you see the reason.

Comment: You're getting an error when you try to open the file the second time, so the program exits and the loop stops.